# SignalR - Mapping ConnectionId to one User on DataBase **(Custom ConnectionId from DB)**

Tags: asp.net, signalr, real-time, signalr-hub

I wonder if there is any way to map a `ConnectionId` to the user without using `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`. I am already using a custom class "IUserIdProvider" to generate a userId

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
     public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        // your logic to fetch a user identifier goes here.
        // for example:

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //**I do not want to use the code below to find the User in my database**
        var userId = MyCustomUserClass.FindUserId(request.User.Identity.Name);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        return userId.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is all because I'm not using ASP.NET authentication method. The real need is to find a way to pass the user ID to make the association with `ConnectionId` of time.

I need a way to give (or receive) the identifier of the data from my database User (user_id) in this method. Or some other way (logic) to associate the user with `ConnectionId`.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters about the connected user in the query string from the client to the server 
like this :

On the client side :

```
$.connection.hub.qs = "myUser=user";
```

On the server side :

```
var myUser= Context.QueryString["myUser"];
```

Comment: I agree, I think this is the way to go, you could use the server side code in your `CustomUserIdProvider`. Just one note, you have to setup the `qs` member before starting the connection, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the personal responses, glad for personal answers, I am grateful to have someone willing to help. With this and using IUserIdProvider how do I get the last id by query string in hub? I still can not use the userid that the genus "GETUSERID (IRequest request)" method.

Comment: a Hub instance  is generated and disposed  for every client meaning it's transient, so the query id , is the query id of the connected client to that hub.  so the Context.QueryString is valid only in the hub.

Comment: Just a correction in syntax:  `$connection.hub.qs = {'version': '1 .0'};`

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler is this dangerous to do from the client? Couldn't a user change this javascript (say they change "user" to "user2") and the server end up storing the wrong user in myUser? Thanks for the help.